# Using Algorithm in Tufte LaTeX is making error in Captions

Tags: tufte, algorithmicx

I am using `algorithm` in Tufte LaTeX

[image: Caption is in the middle, and the horizontal line below it is also missing]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}\captionsetup{font={sc}, labelfont={bf,sc}}
\caption{Batch Gradient Descent Algorithm}\label{alg:batchgradientdescent}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\INPUT $training\text{\_}examples, \alpha, iter$
\Function{GradientDescent}{$X, y, \alpha, iter$}
\State $\theta \gets$ Initialized to small random values
\For{$i \in \{1,\dots,iter\}$} 
    \State $\Delta\theta_i \gets$ 0 \Comment{Initialize each $\Delta\theta_i$ to 0}
    \For{each $(x^i, y^i)$ in $training\_examples$}
        \State $h \gets \theta_0x_0 \dots \theta_nx_n$ \Comment{Compute the output h}
        \For{each parameter $\theta_i$}
            \State $\Delta\theta_i  \gets \Delta\theta_i  + \alpha(y^i - h)x_i $
        \EndFor 
    \EndFor
    \For{each parameter $\theta_i$}
        \State $\theta_i \gets \theta_i + \Delta\theta_i$
    \EndFor

\EndFor
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The code that you provided fails to compile for me. After removing the `\captionsetup` and `\INPUT` lines, it did compile successfully and the caption appeared as expected in the margin note area.

Can you describe the results you're getting and what you're trying to achieve?